# display a kml on rumsey historical map

Tags: kml

i want to diplay a kml (on a public url) on this map
http://rumsey.geogarage.com/maps/g2104028.html?lat=44.22158376545796&lon=10.634765625&zoom=8

any hint to start? 
looking at that page source i see
var map = new geogarage.Maps(document.getElementById("map"), MY_IMAGE, {method:"overlay"});

but i'm not finding anything about geogarage documentation

Comment: 1. You need to use http://www.geogarage.com/gggmap-1.1/geogarage.js as they are tiles

Comment: 2. Ask permission

Answer (score 1):

1. As [Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/276/mapperz) wrote, ask for permission to use those tiles on your map.
2. Use a KML Layer in your google maps api v3 javascript code to overlay your KML file! More info on how to do that can be found here: [KML Layer howto](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)